# Replace character in MySQL varchar

Tags: mysql, replace

I'm trying to convert a column named `A` with `"YYYY/MM/DD"` varchar (already inserted data) to a `"YYYY-MM-DD"` date.  As an example I need the `1987/12/23` (varchar column) data to end up `1987-12-23` (date column), probably using UPDATE and REPLACE.

Comment: Do you mean the [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE table
    SET A = replace(A, '/', '-')
    WHERE A LIKE '____/__/__';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm!(PS. Multumesc, am vazut ca esti si tu RO)

Comment: What do I do if now the column has data like DD-MM-YYYY VARCHAR and I needed to be YYYY-MM-DD DATE ? Thanks again!

Comment: You can ask another question for this because other persons can be interested. I'll give you a hint, and I'll let you transform in an UPDATE statement.
`SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT('10-23-1990',4), "-", SUBSTRING('10-23-1990', 4, 2), "-", LEFT('10-23-1990',2))
    FROM DUAL`

Comment: It worked like this: UPDATE table SET column = CONCAT(RIGHT(column,4), "-", SUBSTRING(column, 4, 2), "-", LEFT(column,2)); Thanks again and have a good night!

Answer (score 1):

As tadman pointed out, you can use the REPLACE function.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `A`=REPLACE(`A`,'/','-')
```